# SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed]

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, windows-server-2012, kibana

Recently our server was rebooted without correctly shutting down the Elastic Search / Kibana. After that reboot, both applications were running but no indices were getting created anymore. I checked logstash setup in debug mode and it is sending data to Elastic Search.

now all my created windows report this error:

```
Oops! SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed]
```

I tried restarting Elastic Search / Kibana, and cleared some indices. I searched a lot but wasn't able to troubleshoot this correctly.

Current Cluster Health Status is RED as shown in picture.

[image: Elastic Search Cluster Health]

Any help as of how to troubleshoot that is upvoted. Thank you

EDIT:

```
[2015-05-06 00:00:01,561][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Indech] [logstash-2015.03.16][1] sending failed shard for [logstash-2015.03.16][1], node[fdSgUPDbQB2B3NQqX7MdMQ], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [aBcfbqnNR4-AGEdIR8dVdg], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[logstash-2015.03.16][1] failed to recover shard]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [101]]; ]]
[2015-05-06 00:00:01,561][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Indech] [logstash-2015.03.16][1] received shard failed for [logstash-2015.03.16][1], node[fdSgUPDbQB2B3NQqX7MdMQ], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [aBcfbqnNR4-AGEdIR8dVdg], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[logstash-2015.03.16][1] failed to recover shard]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No version type match [101]]; ]]
[2015-05-06 00:00:02,591][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [Indech] [logstash-2015.04.21][4] failed to start shard
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [logstash-2015.04.21][4] failed to recover shard
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:269)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: No version type match [52]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.VersionType.fromValue(VersionType.java:307)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.Translog$Create.readFrom(Translog.java:364)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.TranslogStreams.readTranslogOperation(TranslogStreams.java:52)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:241)
```

what concerns me in the logsis this:

```
[2015-05-06 15:13:48,059][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] All shards failed for phase: [query]



{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 8,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 120,
  "active_shards" : 120,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 310
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have many corrupt translog files, which you need to delete. You can find it in `data/{clustername}/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2015.04.21/4/translog` and another one in `data/{clustername}/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2015.03.16/1/translog`. And maybe others, but this is what I can tell from the snippet you provided. Of course, will loose what is in the translog files.

If the indices don't have the index files anymore (only `_state` folder exists under `data/{clustername}/nodes/0/indices/[index_name]`) this means there is no data in that index anymore and at this point you can delete the index. You need to reindex that data, if you still need it. If you decide to delete the indices, you need to shutdown the node and delete the index folders under `data/{clustername}/nodes/0/indices` that are like the one you mentioned (empty, containing just the `_state` folder).

Comment: How to go to the data/{clustername} folder on Macs if you happen to know?

Comment: In my case, my disc was 100% occupied. i increased the volume and rebooted the instance. It worked!

Answer (score 8):

1. Try to delete your index and create it again. Helps sometimes.
2. Or maybe you are trying to query for an `int` and `string` field inside the same query.

Comment: I had to delete the index and rebuild 4 times until it worked

Comment: thanks, i was searching with string field for an int field in terms query, fixing that resolved the error

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This error also comes, when the IndexTemplate for the indices is not defined.