# Failed to execute main query, elasticsearch / Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, centos6

I found that my graph was constantly failing.

I restart my services and it works for a moment and then no longer.

Looking in my logs I found the following exception.

About my server.

Centos 6
125 RAM
15 cores.

My kibana works with the following services.

-logstash
-elasticsearch
-kibana

In my log I have the following information:

```
[2016-12-20 16:29:17,694][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Zeitgeist] [logstash-2016.12.19][0], node[rer0mIPDRPeD7dkjrX9h5A], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@664e869f] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhaseExecutionException: [logstash-2016.12.19][0]: query[filtered((program:httpd) _all:and (syslog_severity:notice))->BooleanFilter(+QueryWrapperFilter(ConstantScore(*:*)) +cache(@timestamp:[1482268665727 TO 1482272265727]))],from[0],size[0]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:301)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:559)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer, 
I delete those files, because they were corrupt.

```
ls /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices
logstash-2016.12.20  
logstash-2016.12.21
```

You can even delete the current day, and it is regenerated.

Then restart services

as reference

[SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073759/searchphaseexecutionexceptionfailed-to-execute-phase-query-all-shards-failed)