# Get RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error') for cossimilarity

Tags: elasticsearch, cosine-similarity

I am trying to do semantic search with Elasticsearch using tensorflow_hub, but I get `RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')` . From search_phase_execution_exception I suppose that with corrupted data([from this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073759/searchphaseexecutionexceptionfailed-to-execute-phase-query-all-shards-failed)) My document structure looks like this

```
{
"settings": {
  "number_of_shards": 2,
  "number_of_replicas": 1
},
 "mappings": {
  "dynamic": "true",
  "_source": {
    "enabled": "true"
  },
  "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type":"keyword"
        },
        "title": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "abstract": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "abs_emb": {
            "type":"dense_vector",
            "dims":512
        },
        "timestamp": {
            "type":"date"
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I create a document using `elasticsearch.indices.create`.

```
es.indices.create(index=index, body='my_document_structure')
res = es.indices.delete(index=index, ignore=[404])
for i in range(100):
  doc = {
    'timestamp': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
    'id':id[i],
    'title':title[0][i],
    'abstract':abstract[0][i],
    'abs_emb':tf_hub_KerasLayer([abstract[0][i]])[0]
  }
  res = es.index(index=index, body=doc)
```

for my semantic search I use this code

query = "graphene"
query_vector = list(embed([query])[0])

```
script_query = {
    "script_score": {
        "query": {"match_all": {}},
        "script": {
            "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, doc['abs_emb']) + 1.0",
            "params": {"query_vector": query_vector}
        }
    }
}

response = es.search(
    index=index,
    body={
        "size": 5,
        "query": script_query,
        "_source": {"includes": ["title", "abstract"]}
    }
)
```

I know there are some similar questions in stackoverflow and elsasticsearch, but I couldn't find solution for me. My guess is that the document structure is wrong but I can't figure out what exactly. I used search query code from [this](https://github.com/jtibshirani/text-embeddings/blob/blog/src/main.py) repo. The full error message is too long and doesn't seem to contain much information, so I share only last part of it.

```
~/untitled/elastic/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py in 
_raise_error(self, status_code, raw_data)
320             logger.warning("Undecodable raw error response from server: %s", err)
321 
--> 322         raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
323             status_code, error_message, additional_info
324         )

RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')
```

An here is the Error from Elasticsearch server.

```
[2021-04-29T12:43:07,797][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] 
[asmac.local] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on 
[w7lUacguTZWH9xc_lyd0kg][asmac.local][/Users/username/elasticsearch- 
7.12.0/data/nodes/0] free: 17.2gb[7.4%], shards will be relocated 
away from this node; currently relocating away shards totalling [0] 
bytes; the node is expected to continue to exceed the high disk 
watermark when these relocations are complete
```

Comment: Can you also add the error log you're seeing in the ES server log?

Comment: @Val It doesn't seem to have an error only the warning.

Comment: You don't see anything related to `search_phase_execution_exception` in the logs?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're hitting the [following issue](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/breaking-changes-7.6.html#_update_to_vector_function_signatures) and you should update your query to this:

```
script_query = {
    "script_score": {
        "query": {"match_all": {}},
        "script": {
            "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'abs_emb') + 1.0",
            "params": {"query_vector": query_vector}
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure that `query_vector` [contains floats and not doubles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/breaking-changes-7.4.html#_use_float_instead_of_double_for_query_vectors)

Comment: I have checked the type and it was numpy.float32 so didn't seem like that was the case. I also updated the code from doc['abs_emb'] to 'abs_emb' , but I still get same error.

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure you should find the error in the ES logs somewhere... Do you have multiple nodes? If not, can you maybe [increase the log level](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.12.0/index.html?highlight=logging#logging) of your Python client to dump the error in your client code logs

Comment: I will check it. Hope this google colab can help to find the problem
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eRvDeO73I_Xiap2X2HZOqgkgUGMwzs4m?usp=sharing

Comment: no I have just one node and I increased the log level to info still no results.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the error was "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.xpack.vect
ors.query.VectorScriptDocValues$DenseVectorScriptDocValues"

My mistake was - I removed the ES index before starting ingesting content. The one that had the "type":"dense_vector" field.

It caused ES did not use the correct type for indexing dense vectors: they were stored as useless lists of doubles. In this sense the ES index was 'corrupted': all 'script_score' queries returned 400.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, because I was using `doc['text_vector']` instead of `'text_vector'`. (see [breaking change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/breaking-changes-7.6.html#_update_to_vector_function_signatures) at 7.6 version of elasticsearch)

Once I've added `json.dumps` I found that `'text_vector'` field was not a `dence_vector`, because of this error message:

```
class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.xpack.vectors.query.VectorScriptDocValues$DenseVectorScriptDocValues
```

And to fix this error, I had to create index with `mappings` field set to:

```
{ "properties": { "text_vector": { "type": "dense_vector", "dims": 3 } } }
```

There `dims` is a size of vector (number of elements in vector).

A function to create index with mapping of types for fields:

```py
def create():
    index = 'text_index'
    body = {
        "settings": {},
        "mappings": { "properties": { "text_vector": { "type": "dense_vector", "dims": 3 } } }
    }
    es.indices.create(index=index, body=body)

    click.echo(f"Index {index} is created with settings {json.dumps(body, indent=4)}")
```

A function to index any string of text:

```py
def index(input_str):
    # text_embedding = embed([input_str])[0].numpy().tolist()
    text_embedding = [4.2, 3.4, -0.2]

    body = {'text': input_str, 'text_vector': text_embedding}
    
    res = es.index(index='text_index', body=body)
    click.echo(f"Indexed {input_str} with id {res['_id']}")
```

A function to execute vector search using elasticsearch for any text string:

```py
def search(search_string):
    # search_vector = embed([search_string])[0].numpy().tolist()
    search_vector = [4.2, 3.4, -0.2]

    body = {
        'query': {
            'script_score': {
                'query': {'match_all': {}},
                'script': {
                    'source': "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'text_vector') + 1.0",
                    'params': {'query_vector': search_vector}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    try:
        res = es.search(index='text_index', body=body)
        click.echo("Search results:")
        for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
            click.echo(f"{doc['_id']} {doc['_score']}: {doc['_source']['text']}")
    except Exception as inst:
        print(type(inst))
        print(json.dumps(inst.args, inden
```

Note: this just an example, adjust `mappings` and embedding vectors that are used to index text and to search text according to your embedding model configuration. If it still does not help then read error carefully at json dump.

Full description of issue: https://github.com/Konard/elastic-search/issues/3

Full source code: https://github.com/Konard/elastic-search/commit/1df0748dd8e8a37c29e1d128eedf96d074e5a73f

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I was using `dense_vector` instead of `elastiknn_dense_float_vector` which is still open issue. I am converting my vector index to use `dense_vector` instead:
https://github.com/alexklibisz/elastiknn/issues/323